# Populate DataTable error

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I'm taking over another guys project, and getting the following error when executing the code below. Error occurs on last line.

> *The type initializer for 'System.Data.Common.DataStorage' threw an
>   exception*

```
string sqlSurvey = "SELECT ID, Name " +
                   "FROM Surveys " +
                   "ORDER BY ID ASC";
DataRow drSurvey = null;
DataTable dtSurvey = data.ExecuteDataSet(sqlSurvey).Tables[0];
```

Comment: step into it and see what is going on.

Comment: It goes into a different DLL whose code I can't see - it's a class that extends the current class.  But the  ExecuteDataSet is just a wrapper for the .Net ExecuteDataSet.  Should work the same.

Answer (score 1):

The DLL that contains the wrapper of ExecuteDataSet is linked incorrectly.  It refers to a path on the other guy's PC.  Remove and relink.